# Is secure save some sensitive data in Localizable.strings?

Tags: ios

My question is very clear. I need save some sensitive static data. For example, the url of my service or a password of encrypt. Now I have the next doubt: Is secure save this data in Localizable.strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A malicious user can easily see this in the IPA of an iTunes backup. But the user can also see this in *any* file in your app bundle. You will need to encrypt the string somehow. The tricky part is to hide the key as well: it may be a good idea to calculate the key somehow (you can be creative here).

Also pay attention to secure your transmission: if you would be using plain HTTP anyone who can use Wireshark would be able to see your sensitive information. Make sure you've set up HTTPS correctly and that you are *validating* the certificate of the server on connect (search StackOverflow about that).

Comment: Thanks, nice response!

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @DarkDust. Just to add more things:

1. A malicious user can see the data because he does the jailbreak on one of the devices. Then he installs the app and may get whole contents of the app. He may change some code and run it.
2. Whole process of getting the data is called reverse engineering. It's quite wide branch and it's good to know the basics if you care about data security.

You may read more about reverse engineering at e.g. this free book: https://github.com/iosre/iOSAppReverseEngineering.

The best hacker always gets the data, it's just the matter of time. For you, as a developer, the task is to forbid getting the data for less experienced "hackers".

To make things more difficult, you can obfuscate the data.

If you need to save some credentials in app (eg login token), always use the keychain, never any other storage.

Comment: Thanks I used the keychain to store user session, I thought the possibility to use it for the others values too. Thanks for response :D